# Can't set a db path?

Tags: mongodb

I've installed mongodb on my mac using homebrew using the following command in terminal:

```
brew services start mongodb
```

However when I try to set the db path, I get the following error:

```
mongod --dbpath
2017-02-24T09:49:08.874+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: mongodb expects it's dbpath at `/data/db` pre-existing if `--dbpath` argument isn't provided. Make sure you have this directory structure created before launching mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this comming in your command promt or can set this path in mongo.conf file what should work for you.

```
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```